# Shooting technique using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-value, boundary-conditions

Here I am attaching my code below. It took all the variable's values, but the graph window was empty. I am not able to recognize, where is the error exactly. Differential equations were also, checked so many times. If any further information is required, please feel free to ask. Can anyone please help me out?

**Thanking You in advance**

**Constant values**

```
\[Epsilon]1 = 0.4;    \[Epsilon]2 = 0.8;   \[Rho]w = 1;
\[Mu]w = 1;    CPw = 1;    \[Kappa]w = 1;    \[Sigma]w = 1;
btw = 1;    bcw = 1;    \[Rho]k = 1;    \[Mu]k = 1;
CPk = 1;    \[Kappa]k = 1;    \[Sigma]k = 1;    \[Beta]tk = 1;
\[Beta]ck = 1;    t = 1;    L = 1;    \[Sigma] = 0.001;
R = 2.5;    H = 1;    Da1 = 0.5;    Da2 = 0.5;    Da3 = 0.5;    \[Beta] = 1;
M = 1;    Gr = 1;    Gc = 1;    \[Theta] = 0;
\[Delta] = 1;    Pr = 1;    Ec = 1;
a1 = 1;    a2 = 1.5;    a3 = 2;    f = 1;
Nb = 1;    Nt = 1;    Le = 1;    \[CapitalGamma] = 1;(*CHEMICAL REACTION PARAMETER*)
K1 = 0.001;     Bi = 1;    n = 1;
```

**Corresponding Variables**

```
\[CurlyTheta] = (\[Mu]w*\[Rho]k)/(\[Mu]k*\[Rho]w);   \[Sigma] = \[Sigma]k/\[Sigma]w;
\[Mu] = \[Mu]k/\[Mu]w;    \[Rho] = \[Rho]w/\[Rho]k;
\[Beta]T = \[Beta]tk/btw;    \[Beta]C = \[Beta]ck/bcw;
Cp = CPw/CPk;    \[Rho]c = (\[Rho]w*CPw)/(\[Rho]k*CPk);
\[Kappa] = \[Kappa]w/\[Kappa]k;    \[Alpha] = (\[Rho]w*CPw*\[Kappa]k)/(\[Kappa]w*\[Rho]k*CPk);    Db = 1; Subscript[D, t] = 1; K = 1; Pr1 = 21;
H1 = Sqrt[\[CurlyTheta]]*H;
R1 = \[CurlyTheta]*R;
M1 = Sqrt[\[Sigma]/\[Mu]]*M;
Gr1 = \[Beta]T*\[CurlyTheta]*Gr;
Gc1 = \[Beta]C*\[CurlyTheta]*Gc;
Ec1 = Cp*Ec;
Nt1 = Nt/(Subscript[D, t]*\[Alpha]);
Nb1 = Nb/(Db*\[Alpha]);
Le1 = \[Alpha]*Le*Db;
\[Gamma]1 = (\[CurlyTheta]*\[CapitalGamma])/K;
K2 = (\[CurlyTheta]*K1)/K;
D1 = (-(1/Da1) - M^2);
D2 = Gr*Sin[\[Theta]];
D3 = Gc*Sin[\[Theta]];
D4 = \[Delta]*(R/H)^2;
D5 = 1/Pr;
D6 = (-a1 + f)/Pr;
D7 = (Ec/Da1 + (M^2*Ec));
D8 = Nb/Pr;
D9 = Nt/Pr;
D10 = Le*Pr*H^2;
```

(* Some more constants  *)
All the constants are getting values properly, all of them I checked.

```
D11 = Le*Pr*R;
D12 = Nt/Nb;
D13 = \[CapitalGamma]*Le*Pr;
D14 = K1*Le*Pr;
D15 = \[Rho]*H1^2;
D16 = (-(1/Da2) - M1^2);
D17 = Gr1*Sin[\[Theta]];
D18 = Gc1*Sin[\[Theta]];
D19 = 1/Pr1;
D20 = \[Delta]*(R1/H1)^2;
D21 = ((-a2 + f)*\[Kappa])/Pr;
D22 = (Ec1/Da2 + Ec1*M1^2);
D23 = (\[Rho]*Cp*Nb1)/Pr1;
D24 = (\[Rho]*Cp*Nt1)/Pr1;
D25 = Le1*Pr1*H1^2;
D26 = Le1*Pr1*R1;
D27 = Nt1/Nb1;
D28 = \[Gamma]1*Le1*Pr1;
D29 = K2*Le1*Pr1;
D30 = (-(1/Da3) - M^2);
D31 = (-a3 + f)/Pr;
D32 = (Ec/Da3 + (M^2*Ec));
```

(* Ordinary Differential equations and boundary conditions *)

```
n1 = 
   NDSolve[{u10''[y] - (R*u10'[y]) + D1*u10[y] + D2*T10[y] + 
       D3*\[Phi]10[y] + H^2 == 0,
     u11''[y] - (R*u11'[y]) + ((D1 - I*H^2)*u11[y]) + D2*T11[y] + 
       D3*\[Phi]11[y] + H^2 == 0,
     ((D5 - D4)*T10''[y]) - (R*T10'[y]) - (D6*
         T10[y]) + (Ec*(u10'[y])^2) + (D7*(u10[y])^2) + (D8*\[Phi]10'[
          y]*T10'[y]) + (D9*T10'[y]^2) == 0,
     ((D5 - D4)*T11''[y]) - (R*T11'[y]) - ((D6 + I*H^2)*T11[y]) + (2*
         Ec*u11'[y]*u10'[y]) + (2*D7*u11[y]*
         u10[y]) + (D8*(\[Phi]11'[y]*T10'[y] + \[Phi]10'[y]*
            T11'[y])) + (2*D9*T11'[y]*T10'[y]) == 0,
     \[Phi]10''[y] - (D11*\[Phi]10'[y]) - (D13*\[Phi]10[y]) + 
       D12*T10''[y] - (D14) == 0,
     \[Phi]11''[
        y] - (D11*\[Phi]11'[y]) - ((D13 + I*D10)*\[Phi]11[y]) + 
       D12*T11''[y] == 0,
     ((1 + 1/\[Beta])*u20''[y]) - (R1*u20'[y]) + (D16*u20[y]) + (D17*
         T20[y]) + (D18*\[Phi]20[y]) + D15 == 0,
     ((1 + 1/\[Beta])*u21''[y]) - (R1*u21'[y]) + ((D16 - I*H1^2)*
         u21[y]) + (D17*T21[y]) + (D18*\[Phi]21[y]) + D15 == 0,
     ((D19 - D20)*T20''[y]) - (R1*T20'[y]) - (D21*
         T20[y]) + (Ec1*(1 + 1/\[Beta])*(u20'[y])^2) + (D22*(u20[
           y])^2) + (D23*\[Phi]20'[y]*T20'[y]) + (D24*T20'[y]^2) == 
      0,
     ((D19 - D20)*T21''[y]) - (R1*T21'[y]) - ((D21 + I*H1^2)*
         T21[y]) + (2*Ec1*(1 + 1/\[Beta])*u20'[y]*u21'[y]) + (2*D22*
         u20[y]*u21[
          y]) + (D23*(\[Phi]20'[y]*T21'[y] + \[Phi]21'[y]*
            T20'[y])) + (2*D24*T20'[y]*T21'[y]) == 0,
     \[Phi]20''[y] - (D26*\[Phi]20'[y]) - (D28*\[Phi]20[y]) + 
       D27*T20''[y] - (D29) == 0,
     \[Phi]21''[
        y] - (D26*\[Phi]21'[y]) - ((D28 + I*D25)*\[Phi]21[y]) + 
       D27*T21''[y] == 0,
     u30''[y] - (R*u30'[y]) + D30*u30[y] + D2*T30[y] + 
       D3*\[Phi]30[y] + H^2 == 0,
     u31''[y] - (R*u31'[y]) + ((D30 - I*H^2)*u31[y]) + D2*T31[y] + 
       D3*\[Phi]31[y] + H^2 == 0,
     ((D5 - D4)*T30''[y]) - (R*T30'[y]) - (D31*
         T30[y]) + (Ec*(u30'[y])^2) + (D32*(u30[
           y])^2) + (D8*\[Phi]30'[y]*T30'[y]) + D9*T30'[y]^2 == 0,
     ((D5 - D4)*T31''[y]) - (R*T31'[y]) - ((D31 + I*H^2)*T31[y]) + (2*
         Ec*u30'[y]*u31'[y]) + (2*D32*u30[y]*
         u31[y]) + (D8*(\[Phi]30'[y]*T31'[y] + \[Phi]31'[y]*
            T30'[y])) + (2*D9*T30'[y]*T31'[y]) == 0,
     \[Phi]30''[y] - (D11*\[Phi]30'[y]) - (D13*\[Phi]30[y]) + 
       D12*T30''[y] - (D14) == 0,
     \[Phi]31''[
        y] - (D11*\[Phi]31'[y]) - ((D13 + I*D10)*\[Phi]31[y]) + 
       D12*T31''[y] == 0,
     u10[0] == L*u10'[0], u11[0] == L*u11'[0], u30[1] == -L*u30'[1], 
     u31[1] == -L*u31'[1], u10[\[Epsilon]1] == u20[\[Epsilon]1], 
     u11[\[Epsilon]1] == u21[\[Epsilon]1], 
     u20[\[Epsilon]2] == u30[\[Epsilon]2], 
     u21[\[Epsilon]2] == u31[\[Epsilon]2], 
     u10'[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Mu]*u20'[\[Epsilon]1], 
     u11'[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Mu]*u21'[\[Epsilon]1], 
     u30'[\[Epsilon]2] == \[Mu]*u20'[\[Epsilon]2], 
     u31'[\[Epsilon]2] == \[Mu]*u21'[\[Epsilon]2],
     T10'[0] == -Bi*(T10[0]),
     T11'[0] == -Bi*(T11[0]), T30'[1] == -Bi*(T30[1] - 1), 
     T31'[1] == -Bi*(T31[1]), T10[\[Epsilon]1] == T20[\[Epsilon]1], 
     T11[\[Epsilon]1] == T21[\[Epsilon]1], 
     T20[\[Epsilon]2] == T30[\[Epsilon]2], 
     T21[\[Epsilon]2] == 
      T31[\[Epsilon]2], \[Kappa]*T10'[\[Epsilon]1] == 
      T20'[\[Epsilon]1], \[Kappa]*T11'[\[Epsilon]1] == 
      T21'[\[Epsilon]1], \[Kappa]*T30'[\[Epsilon]2] == 
      T20'[\[Epsilon]2], \[Kappa]*T31'[\[Epsilon]2] == 
      T21'[\[Epsilon]2],
     \[Phi]10'[0] == -n*(\[Phi]10[0]),
     \[Phi]11'[0] == -n*(\[Phi]11[0]), \[Phi]30'[
       1] == -n*(\[Phi]30[1] - 1), \[Phi]31'[
       1] == -n*(\[Phi]31[
         1]), \[Phi]10[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Phi]20[\[Epsilon]1], \
\[Phi]11[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Phi]21[\[Epsilon]1], \[Phi]20[\[Epsilon]2] \
== \[Phi]30[\[Epsilon]2], \[Phi]21[\[Epsilon]2] == \
\[Phi]31[\[Epsilon]2], 
     Db*\[Phi]10'[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Phi]20'[\[Epsilon]1], 
     Db*\[Phi]11'[\[Epsilon]1] == \[Phi]21'[\[Epsilon]1], \[Phi]20'[\
\[Epsilon]2] == Db*\[Phi]30'[\[Epsilon]2], \[Phi]21'[\[Epsilon]2] == 
      Db*\[Phi]31'[\[Epsilon]2]}, {u10, u20, u30, u11, u21, u31, T10, 
     T20, T30, T11, T21, 
     T31, \[Phi]10, \[Phi]20, \[Phi]30, \[Phi]11, \[Phi]21, \
\[Phi]31}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", 
        "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}}];
```

(* Plot command *)

```
p1 = Plot[
  Piecewise[{{Re[(u30[y] + (\[Sigma]*(E^(I*t))*u31[y])) /. 
       n1], \[Epsilon]2 <= y <= 
      1}, {Re[(u20[y] + (\[Sigma]*(E^(I*t))*u21[y])) /. 
       n1], \[Epsilon]1 <= 
      y <= \[Epsilon]2}, {Re[(u10[
          y] + (\[Sigma]*(E^(I*t))*u11[y])) /. n1], 
     0 <= y <= \[Epsilon]1}}], {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your data uploaded without semicolon. Please, put `;` in the end in every position with definitions like  `D32 = (Ec/Da3 + (M^2*Ec));`

Comment: @AlexTrounev done sir

Comment: In few minutes we have a message `NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at y == 0.8557735490281189; unable to continue`. With options `PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5`  code generates some solution, but also with errors.

Comment: Yes sir, is there any way sir we can rectify this problem @AlexTrounev

Comment: We can solve this problem with the Euler wavelets collocation method.

Comment: Can we solve this with shooting technique sir @AlexTrounev

Comment: Several of the ODEs can be solved symbolically with `DSolve`.  Do that first to reduce the dimensionality of the problem.

Comment: Respected @bbgodfrey, it is a non-dimensional form of the system of ODEs.

Answer (score 5):

**Original solution**

With a bit of assistance, `NDSolve` can solve these ODEs using the Shooting method.  To begin, set the `List` of ODEs and boundary conditions in the question to `eqs` and then split it into three parts.

```
eq0 = Cases[eqs, z_ /; MemberQ[z, T10[_] | T20[_] | T30[_] | ϕ10[_] | 
    ϕ20[_] | ϕ30[_] | T10'[_] | T20'[_] | T30'[_] | 
    ϕ10'[_] | ϕ20'[_] | ϕ30'[_], Infinity] && 
    ! MemberQ[z, T11[_] | T21[_] | T31[_] | ϕ11[_] | ϕ21[_] | 
    ϕ31[_] | T11'[_] | T21'[_] | T31'[_] | ϕ11'[_] | 
    ϕ21'[_] | ϕ31'[_], Infinity]];

eq1 = Cases[eqs, z_ /; MemberQ[z, T11[_] | T21[_] | T31[_] | ϕ11[_] | 
    ϕ21[_] | ϕ31[_] | T11'[_] | T21'[_] | T31'[_] | 
    ϕ11'[_] | ϕ21'[_] | ϕ31'[_], Infinity]];

equ = Complement[eqs, eq0, eq1];
```

The point of doing so is that `equ` can be solved symbolically.

```
su = DSolve[equ, {u10, u20, u30, u11, u21, u31}, {y, 0, 1}] // 
    Simplify // Flatten;
```

Next, use `su` to eliminate `{u10, u20, u30, u11, u21, u31}` from `eq0` and solve it numerically to obtain solutions for `{T10, T20, T30, ϕ10, ϕ20, ϕ30}`.

```
Chop@Simplify[eq0 /. su];
s0 = NDSolve[%, {T10, T20, T30, ϕ10, ϕ20, ϕ30}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    {T10[ϵ2] == 0, T20[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ10[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ20[ϵ2] == 0, 
     T10'[ϵ2] == 0, T20'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ10'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ20'[ϵ2] == 0}}] // Flatten;
```

Note that the Shooting starts from `y = ϵ2` instead of the default `y = 0`. to avoid the error message given in the question.  Finally, eliminate all the variables obtained so far to solve `eq1` numerically.

```
Chop@Simplify[eq1 /. su /. s0];
s1 = NDSolve[%, {T11, T21, T31, ϕ11, ϕ21, ϕ31}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    {T11[ϵ2] == 0, T21[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ11[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ21[ϵ2] == 0, 
    T11'[ϵ2] == 0, T21'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ11'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ21'[ϵ2] == 0}}] // Flatten;
```

Plots of the solutions are given by

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate@Through[su[[All, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[s0[[All, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate@Through[s1[[All, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

That the solutions satisfy the boundary conditions can be verified, if desired, by back-substitution.  For instance,

```
(Subtract @@@ eq0[[7 ;;]]) /. s0
(* {1.54431*10^-9, -2.29796*10^-11, 5.62184*10^-10, 0., 
    1.27355*10^-8, 0., 2.1361*10^-8, -2.97741*10^-10, 2.46916*10^-9, 0., 
    7.96958*10^-8, 0.} *)
```

**Second, simpler solution**

```
sall = NDSolve[eqs, {u10, u20, u30, u11, u21, u31, T10, T20, 
    T30, ϕ10, ϕ20, ϕ30, T11, T21, T31, ϕ11, ϕ21, ϕ}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    {T10[ϵ2] == 0, T20[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ10[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ20[ϵ2] == 0, T10'[ϵ2] == 0, 
     T20'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ10'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ20'[ϵ2] == 0, T11[ϵ2] == 0, T21[ϵ2] == 0, 
     ϕ11[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ21[ϵ2] == 0, T11'[ϵ2] == 0, T21'[ϵ2] == 0, ϕ11'[ϵ2] == 0, 
     ϕ21'[ϵ2] == 0, u10[ϵ2] == 0, u20[ϵ2] == 0, u10'[ϵ2] == 0, u20'[ϵ2] == 0, 
     u11[ϵ2] == 0, u21[ϵ2] == 0, u11'[ϵ2] == 0, u21'[ϵ2] == 0}}] // Flatten
```

Then,

```
ReImPlot[Evaluate@Through[sall[[;; 6, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
ReImPlot[Evaluate@Through[sall[[7 ;; 12, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
ReImPlot[Evaluate@Through[sall[[13 ;;, 2]][y]], {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

reproduces the plots above.  So, why does this work while the similar approach in the question does not?  A possibility is that shooting from `y = ϵ2` instead of the default `y = 0` requires fewer elements (24 instead of 30) for "StartingInitialConditions".  Also, `y = ϵ2` is closer to where a few of the solutions become large (of order 350).  A better response, however, might be, "Who knows?"  I have found the error, "nderr: Error test failure" to occur somewhat randomly in `NDSolve` calculations.  The only suggestion in the documentation, to try `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` does not help here.

Comment: Thank you so much, @bbgodfre sir, for the help, but this is very difficult for me to understand. Can you please explain it in easy language?

Comment: @KomalGoyal The second solution, which I added a few hours ago, probably is easier to follow

Comment: @bbgodfrey Second solution is very good (+1).

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Please can you intervene in the post bellow for the numerical resolution of a difficult algebraic equation, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279693/58233