# Plot all real and imaginary roots of FindRoot (2)

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

Following the comment of our friend @Bob Hanlon's in my post [Plot all real and imaginary roots of FindRoot vrs `k`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279569/58233), which I would like to thank again for the assistance it gave, I'm creating a new post here. As I clarified with @BobHanlon, my problem is to solve a complicated algebraic equation including an integral and then plot all the real `Re[x]` and imaginary `Im[x]` parts of the roots `x` versus `k`, `t` and `a` parameters.

Equation to solve is

```
eq[x_,k_,t_,a_] := 1 -( k^2/x^2) -((t^2) /(2 BesselK[2, t] k^2))
NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s^2-1] ((1 + (a/x)) - (x /k) Sqrt[s^2/(s^2 - 1)] ((1 + (a/x))^2 - ( 
(s^2 - 1) k^2)/(s^2 x^2))ArcTanh[(Sqrt[(s^2 - 1)/s^2] k)/(x(1 + (a/x )))]) Exp[-t s], 
{s,1, \[Infinity]}]
```

with `0.001 <= t <= 1000`, `0 <= k <= 100` and `a = 25`

To my knowledge, I suppose that this equation can only be solved by `FindRoot` (`SolveValues` gives nothing), which I do not master well, especially the choice of the initial value and precisions of the computations, ...

Here is my code

```
rootx[k_,t_,a_]:=FindRoot[1 -( k^2/x^2) -((t^2) /(2 BesselK[2, t] k^2)) 
NIntegrate[s Sqrt[s ^2 -1] ((1 + (a/x)) - (x /k) Sqrt[s^2/(s^2 - 1)] ((1 + (a/x))^2 - (( 
s^2 - 1) k^2)/(s^2 x^2)) ArcTanh[(Sqrt[(s^2 - 1)/s^2] k)/(x(1 + (a/x)))]) Exp[-t s], 
{s,1, \[Infinity]}]== 0, {x, 1 + 0.01 I}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]


(* Real root of x *)
rex[k_,t_,a_]:=Re[rootx[k,t,a]]
(* rex gives a one real root for a given (k,t,a) but I'm trying to plot all real roots *)

(* Imaginary root of x *)
imx[k_,t_,a_]:=Im[rootx[k,t,a]]
(* imx gives a one imaginary root for a given (k,t,a) but I'm trying to plot all imaginary roots *)
```

Please, how can I know if the initial value `x=1+0.01 I` is the right value who gives the right roots? and how to plot all the `Re` and `Im` roots vrs `k,t,a` ?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq[x_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ,
  a_?NumericQ, wp_ : 10] :=
 1 - (k^2/x^2) - ((t^2)/(2 BesselK[2, t] k^2))*
   NIntegrate[
    s Sqrt[s^2 - 
       1]* ((1 + (a/x)) - (x/k) Sqrt[
         s^2/(s^2 - 1)]*((1 + (a/x))^2 - ((s^2 - 1) k^2)/(s^2 x^2))*
        ArcTanh[(Sqrt[(s^2 - 1)/s^2] k)/(x (1 + (a/x)))]) Exp[-t s], {s, 
     1, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]
```

To get estimates of the roots (starting values for use with `FindRoot`) for specific values of `{k, t}`, look at the plot of `Abs[eq]^2`

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{k, t},
  k = Rationalize[kv, 0];
  t = Rationalize[tv, 0];
  ComplexPlot3D[
   {Abs[eq[x, k, t, 25]]^2, 0},
   {x, -10 - 5*I, 10 + 5*I},
   PlotRange -> {-1/2, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75],
   AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im", None},
   ClippingStyle -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 3,
   SphericalRegion -> True]],
 {{kv, 3, "k"}, 0.01, 100, 0.5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tv, 10, "t"}, 0.001, 1000, 5,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {kv, tv}]
```

[image]

The roots are where the upper curves intersect the plane at `z == 0`

**EDIT:** Manipulating the plots above suggests that the roots are located near `x == k` and `x == -k` with small if any imaginary parts.

```
root[k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] :=
 x /. FindRoot[eq[x, k, t, a, 20] == 0, {x, #}] & /@
  {-k + I/10, k + I/10}

SetOptions[RandomReal, WorkingPrecision -> 20];

SeedRandom[1234];

rgn = ImplicitRegion[10^-3 <= t <= 1000 && 0 < k <= 100, {k, t}];
```

Generate random points in the `{k, t}` plane

```
pts = RandomPoint[rgn, 200];

roots = Transpose[
    Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]], root[#[[1]], #[[2]], 25]}] & /@ pts] // Quiet;

Show[
 ListPlot3D[Re[roots],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
     {k, t, "Re[roots]"}),
  PlotLabel -> "a = 25"],
 ListPointPlot3D[roots,
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
rootsIm = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], Im[#[[3]]]} &, roots, {2}];
```

Most of the imaginary component of the roots are negligible

```
MinMax[#[[All, 3]]] & /@ rootsIm

(* {{-0.000172782, 0.000508208}, 
    {-5.41156*10^-14, 5.58909*10^-13}} *)

Show[
 ListPlot3D[rootsIm,
  PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
     {k, t, "Im[roots]"}),
  PlotLabel -> "a = 25"],
 ListPointPlot3D[rootsIm,
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
kvalues = Range[0, 100, 2] /. {0 -> 10^-3};

data = With[{t = 10, a = 25}, 
    Transpose@Table[Thread[{k, root[k, t, a]}], 
       {k, kvalues}]] // Quiet;

ListLinePlot[Re@data]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[data /. Complex[r_, i_] :> i, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon, but how to plot all the `Re[x]` and `Im[x]` roots?

Comment: Use the plots to come up with estimates to use in FindRoot.

Comment: The computation time of starting values for specific values of `{k,t}`, @BobHanlon, is very long . In addition, I did not succeed in plotting the roots.

Comment: Sorry, I have to admit I'm a bit confused, I couldn't plot all the `Re[x]` and `Im[x]` roots.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bob Hanlon for this great wonderful job you are doing. Last thing please, how to plot `Re[x]` as a function of `k` and `Im[x]` as a function of `k` for `0<=k<=100` and for a fixed value of `t`, for example `t=10`?

Comment: Thank you very much Sir @Bob Hanlon, I'm very grateful for your help. So I wanted to know why you didn't apply the previous code you used to solve the equation from the previous post? Secondly the roots `Re[root]` must also give a positive third root of small value, but I can't find it, and thirdly when I plot the real roots `Re[roots]` for a very small `k` in particular `0.001<= k <= 0.5` gives instabilities (see figure here https://ibb.co/qn6MrMQ), any idea how to fix them please?

Comment: That is just how I chose to do it. If you want to use another method, do so. Using `kvalues = Range[0, 14, 1/4] /. {0 -> 10^-3};` the plot is as expected. As you get close to `k == 0` there are likely to be precision issues since `eq` is undefined for `k == 0`. You did not show your code and I don't know what you did. I did not see a third root in the `Manipulate` so I cannot tell you what initial values to use to find it. I have lost interest in this, don't ask me any further questions.

Comment: Ok, thank you once again for everything Sir @Bob Hanlon, I'm really sorry for the inconvenience.